# Re-grouping data based on report run time

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

I have a folder which serves as a container for a standardized report from a system. This report is run on a daily basis. However, the report may require re-run for a certain date or range of dates depending on user preferences and asks. Thus file content may change significantly.

I would like to create a script that would group the unique dates together in one dataframe based on the latest run time, and another dataframe for the dates that are being revised.

Here is a simplified version of the table:

```
structure(list(Source = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("11-Feb-20", "12-Feb-20"
), class = "factor"), FarmType = structure(c(3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("AJSKJA", 
"ASKJKA", "GHDGH", "KLKIUK", "KLSAKJ"), class = "factor"), FarmName = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("", 
"JJHGH", "JKJKK", "JUISO", "SDLLS"), class = "factor"), Perform = c(13.04144378, 
1.230474165, 1.230474165, 13.9407486, 13.9407486, 13.04144378, 
1.230474165, 1.230474165, 13.9407486, 13.9407486, 13.04144378, 
15.26566, 1.230474165, 13.9407486), RunDate = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("02/14/2020", 
"02/15/2020"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Please note that the number of columns does not change, however, after each re-run the number of rows may increase/decrease.

The idea is -- the first group of data that is based on the most recent run would represent the up-to-date information (corrections, revisions, etc.), while the second group essentially looks at what is being revised and how the numbers and data are changing.

Expected output for the first group:

```
structure(list(Source = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("11-Feb-20", 
    "12-Feb-20"), class = "factor"), FarmType = structure(c(3L, 
    4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("AJSKJA", "ASKJKA", 
    "GHDGH", "KLKIUK", "KLSAKJ"), class = "factor"), FarmName = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("", "JJHGH", 
    "JKJKK", "JUISO", "SDLLS"), class = "factor"), Perform = c(13.04144378, 
    15.26566, 1.230474165, 13.9407486, 13.04144378, 1.230474165, 
    1.230474165, 13.9407486, 13.9407486), RunDate = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("02/14/2020", 
    "02/15/2020"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Expected output for the second group:

```
structure(list(Source = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "11-Feb-20", class = "factor"), 
    FarmType = structure(c(3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("AJSKJA", "ASKJKA", "GHDGH", "KLKIUK", "KLSAKJ"
    ), class = "factor"), FarmName = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("", "JJHGH", "JKJKK", 
    "JUISO", "SDLLS"), class = "factor"), Perform = c(13.04144378, 
    1.230474165, 1.230474165, 13.9407486, 13.9407486, 13.04144378, 
    15.26566, 1.230474165, 13.9407486), RunDate = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("02/14/2020", 
    "02/15/2020"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Thank you for your time. Please let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Can you sspecify the columns to order

Comment: `Date` column should be ordered.

Comment: In my answer, i reordered based on 'Date' and got the identical results as your expected.  Not sure, whether I missed anything

Comment: Yeah, that was confusing to me too. I just wanted to clarify how did you get that result without referencing the `RunDate`. I mean I can see the results, but do not understantd what is it doing.

Comment: May be your input example and expected output was. just a coincidence.  IIn my solution, I looped over the unique elementss of 'Source', the `filter`ed the rows where it is not matching with the 'Ssource' and then ordered based on the 'Date'

Comment: Sorry, not clear to me

Comment: What I am worried about is that if the `Source` is the same for different `RunDate`s, then your code may not work properly.

Comment: My point is that I am not getting the logic correctly about how you are splitting

Comment: I was trying to understand the description `(corrections, revisions, etc`.  Is it based on Date or some other column value

Comment: Let's say if you have unique dates `11-Feb-20`, `12-Feb-20`, `13-Feb-20`, and `14-Feb-20`, how many datasets you have as expected output

Comment: Yes, these corrections, revisions, etc. can be applied to any row and potentially some rows may get removed if they were incorrectly included (or added if they were missing from in the previous run). What I was thinking was like look at the `Date` and `RunDate` columns. If the `RunDate` is the same, then keep it [GROUP1 dataframe], otherwise remove it to GROUP2 with the latest result for further comparison.

Comment: In your example, the `RunDate` is same for Source 1 and 2, but you are splitting it up

Comment: If there we no re-runs, then I would not expect GROUP2, i.e. only one dataset.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207907/discussion-between-akrun-and-ak88).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could group by 'Date' and `filter` those groups where the 'RunDate' is the latest after converting to `Date` class

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
new1 <- df1 %>%
            group_by(Date) %>%
            filter(mdy(RunDate) == max(mdy(RunDate)))
```

and for the second set, we can check if the number of distinct elements of 'RunDate' is more than 1

```
new2 <- df1 %>%
            group_by(Date) %>%
            filter(n_distinct(RunDate) > 1)
```